# Issues connecting CSS with HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have been having some issues with using an external stylesheet and connecting it to HTML (really simple, right).

I've been copying really simple examples off the Internet a few lines long to see if something is wrong with my code and while the HTML part works (I see the words), when I use an external CSS, none of the styles are applied.

See my code below. I am trying to not use `<style></style>`. I am trying to get red text:

```css
    h1 {
     color: red;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Framework Test Page</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is `main.css` in the same folder as the HTML file?

Comment: When you open up the html page in your browser, open the debugger (F12), check network to see if your css was loaded, chances are it wasn't. You probably have to fix the path in the href as Coda17 is implying.

Comment: Post the stylesheet - if you're missing a bracket, quote, or semicolon your style may not work. CSS won't throw an error if it's invalid - it just won't work.

Comment: Hi. It is working now by putting it in the same file. I had done that earlier, but it didn't work--for some reason. I just did it again and it is working--for some reason. I was using an example from Udacity that says that a folder called Framework and in it have a subfolder called CSS where in that folder you have your CSS file. Under framework still keep your .html file (so the CSS folder and .html file are in the same folder called "Framework." Framework was in an empty folder called "Portfolio," which was under a folder called "HTML CSS." Anyways, I guess problem solved?! Thank you.

Comment: Split the code into a separate block for html and the css, added as a snippet to show nothing wrong with example, and escaped the <> for style.

Answer (score 0):

chaeck whater the css file contain css rules for you html element and the css file is in the same folder. because there is no  any css rule(css) aply for this html file. Another thing is you can not use

```
h1{
    color:red;
}
```

Like this. You sholud use that part inside `<style></style>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your main.css needs to be in the same folder as you html file. If you have your css file in a css folder then use `css/main.css`

Also if you are doing style changes in the html file (which you shouldn't really do), put those changes in style tags:

`<style>
  h1{color:red;}
 </style>`

Comment: The styling closer to the content will override what came before it, too. (External is applied first, then document level, then inline)

Comment: Thanks, just took this advice!